# Flickr and Youtube integration on Android

Tags: android, youtube, flickr

HI ALL

I need to show :

1) Photostream of a particular account on flickr in a grid view.
2) List OR Grid of you tube videos for a particular channel.

Please suggest tutorials OR link to do that.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For flicker use "[photostream app](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/android-photostream.html)" and for showing youtube channels use gdata api OR if you simply need to show videos in a list view and play them. You can parse the response from following url:

**http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads**

get the data from every "entry" tag. Use the following intent to play the url in youtube app:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse("vnd.youtube:" + url));
                startActivity(i);
```